# How is Koin Dependency Injection better if I have to initialize dependencies insdie the body of the class?

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I am using dependency injection for the first time and decided to use Koin since it is more suitable for small projects.

**WITHOUT dependency injection:**

```
class ParserDAO(private val connection: Connection){
// body of the code
}
```

**WITH dependency injection:**

```
class ParserDAO : KoinComponent {
    private val connection: Connection by inject<Connection>()
    // body
}
```

I don't understand how the dependency-injected version is better, instead of passing the Connection object through the constructor I am having to do it inside the body of the DAO class. I could have just created the instance or passed the instance of Connection without the dependency injection and it would have worked out the same more or less.

**Here is the module file for Koin:**

```
val appModule = module {

    // creates the Connection instane
 single {
     LocalDatabase("jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/database.db").connection
 }

 factory {
     ParserDAO()
 }

single {
     TransactionAugmentor()
 }

 single {
     ParserController()
 }

}
```

I am wanting to understand how is DI (at lesat with Koin) is better. Please point out if I have done anything incorrectly.

I have compared my code with and without DI and I think DI only seems to be adding more code and complexity without anyimprovement to the code.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of documentation, articles, theory (such as SOLID) on the uses of dependency injection that you can check out.

In practice, I find it most useful for easily managing resources that you only have one of and that are expensive to initialise. You would have to write a lot of code to pass around a database connection for example - it would end up being a parameter in almost every method. You would also have to consider contention as different asynchronous threads or coroutines tried to use the same connection. This applies to other similar resources like HTTP clients, memory caches like redis, other dbs, etc.

The other main advantage is for testing and various environments. It's easier to manager which host urls for connections, mocked resources for testing, etc. will be used by swapping out pre-configured modules. This way the service code is unaware/dependent on the environment it's actually being ran in.

Koin specifically follows more of a service-locator pattern than dependency-injection. I prefer this to other DI libraries because the logic is explicitly written in modules, vs using annotations to "magically" bind everything.

Answer (score 1):

You should read a little about dependency injection because it seems that you don't understand the concept well enough.

Both of you examples use dependency injection, the first one uses constructor injection the second one field injection. In my opinion constructor injection should be favoured where possible as it makes the code a lot easier to read and follow.

Using Koin you can create constructor injection by using the following code:

```
val appModule = module {

// creates the Connection instane
 single {
     LocalDatabase("jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/database.db").connection
 }

 factory {
     ParserDAO(connection = get<Connection>())
 }

 single {
     TransactionAugmentor()
 }

 single {
     ParserController()
 }

}
```